# How to modify my current data set in order to plot desired box plot using Seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I want to see the median as well as outliers using boxplot (seaborn). I want all boxes for all customers in a single plot . Example data looks like this:

Surveyed some drivers to capture how many times they press horn each day.

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST3Jh.png)

The numbers represent the number of times horn was pressed.

I want to make boxplots for each customer to identify outliers. Actual data is quite big.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("//Name of file")
df.boxplot(y='Customer 1', data =df)

But using this I will get box plot for only 1 customer, I want all boxes for all customers in single plot

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can pass vectors of data represented as lists, numpy arrays, or pandas Series to the Seaborn boxplot function.

For example

```
import seaborn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("your.csv")
seaborn.boxplot(data=df)
```

This will result in the following figure.

[image]

An alternative would be `df.boxplot()` which will result in the following figure
[image]

Comment: Please check the dataset image I have added in question. I am trying to read data from csv with pandas and then trying to plot boxplot for each customer

Comment: you can read your .csv file with the following line of code
df = pd.read_csv("your.csv") this will return a dataframe